# Swing: Check if any component falls out of screen

Tags: java, swing, screen, jlabel, boxlayout

I am displaying a bunch of `JLabels` one below the other **using a loop**; my `JPanel` has  `BoxLayout`.
How can I check whether any `JLabel` **falls out of screen**?

Comment: That's a complicated issue which could be better solved by using a `JScrollPane`, but the basic idea would be to check the location of the component compared to the height of the container, but you'll need to do so only AFTER a layout pass has been run

Comment: Can you tell me the reason you want to know that?

Comment: To be honest I did not know the existence of `JScrollPane`, so I wanted to fit all labels in one single fixed frame. Now I'll try with `JScrollPane` :)

Comment: *"Now I'll try with `JScrollPane`"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Ok :) @AndrewThompson

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer I am ok with `JScrollPane`.